# How to catch PyQtGraph exceptions/errors?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

Normally, to catch exceptions in Python, you would use a try/except handler with a specific error such as `AttributeError` or `KeyError`.

But the PyQtGraph exception output to console does not have a specific handler that you can catch. Here's an example of the error output

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotCurveItem.py", line 353, in updateData
>
> raise Exception("X and Y arrays must be the same shape--got %s and %s." % (self.xData.shape, self.yData.shape))
>
> Exception: X and Y arrays must be the same shape--got (1L,) and (2001L,).

Typically I would do a try/except block with a particular exception like this.

```
try:
    ...
except AttributeError:
    ...
```

I also don't want to just use except without a specific exception. I understand that the exception is caused by not giving `setData()` the same size X and Y axis Numpy arrays but I was wondering how I would be able to catch PyQtGraph exceptions in general.

I'm using PyQtGraph v0.10.0

Comment: heya @nathancy, if you upvoted my answer, please also accept it. thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the source available [here](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotCurveItem.html#PlotCurveItem.setData) and at your error message, it appears that pyqtgraph is throwing [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) (notice AttributeError is among those)

You can't get any more specific than that if pyqtgraph isn't either.

```
try:
    # ...
except Exception:
    # ...
```